# .VOB file not compatible with anything I try

Tags: dvd, format

I recently bought two DVD movies at the local store, and, trying to watch the movie on my computer, it doesn´t work. All files are in the .VOB format.

I've looked at other people having similar issues but mine is a bit different. I just put in the DVD and play it but it doesnt work.
I have all kinds of players, from VLC to Dragon Player and Totem and several others.

Please don't give me any programming tips, i can't program. (Which is why I use Ubuntu, ubuntu claiming to be "linux for human beings"

I don't know what a directory or root is, i'm a noob.
I just want to watch a movie.

Comment: Did you try opening the folder of the DVD and play each file with VLC player by right-clicking and choosing "Play with VLC media player"?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to play them directly. Use VLC to play the actual disk, not the files.